# How find this maximum and minimum of the value $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}[x_{i+1}-x_{i}]$

Tags: inequality

**Question:**

> let $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}\in \mathbb{R}$,and Assume that the following two sets are equivalent;
>
> $$\{[x_{1}],[x_{2}],[x_{3}],\cdots,[x_{n}],\}=\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\},n\ge 2 $$
>
> Find the maximum and minimum of
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}[x_{i+1}-x_{i}]$$

where $[x]$ is is the biggest integer not greater than $x$.

My idea: since I consider simple  case

when $n=2$, then
$$\{[x_{1}],[x_{2}]\}=\{1,2\}$$
then it is clear
$$[x_{1}-x_{2}]_{min}=-2$$

$$[x_{1}-x_{2}]_{max}=1$$

and for general I can't solve it.Thank you

Comment: Oh,Thank you,@Macavity,are you think this problem is interesting?

Comment: Yes, though looks like it may take time. Will sleep on it. The max looks easier, as $[x-y]_{max} = |[x]-[y]|$. So we need optimise only among integers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor#1\right\rfloor}
$To begin with I am going to restate the question, for two reasons.
First, the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ is known as the **floor** of $x$
and is nowadays written $\floor{x}$;
you'll see the notation $[x]$ only in older mathematical literature.
Besides that, you should always strive to formulate *clearly* whatever mathematics
you are communicating.
It seems you did not put enough time into writing your question.
Can you afford to spend just five minutes more? A couple of minutes?

Your question is:

> Let $x_1$, $x_2$, $\ldots$, $x_n$ ($n\geq 2$) be real numbers such that
>   $$
> \{\floor{x_1},\floor{x_2},\ldots,\floor{x_n}\}
>     \:=\: \{1,2,\ldots,n\}~. \tag{1}
> $$
>   Find the maximum and the minimum of
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\floor{x_{i+1}-x_i}~.
> $$

The plan of solution: first we shall determine an upper and a lower bound
for the sum in question, denote it by $S$;
then, with these two bounds in hand, we shall prove that they are in fact
the maximum and the minimum.

$\newcommand{\fracpart}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
$Given a real number $x$, let $\fracpart{x}$ denote the **fractional part** of $x$,
defined by $\fracpart{x} := x-\floor{x}$. Always $0\leq{\fracpart{x}}<1$.
(The accepted notation for the fractional part of $x$ is $\{x\}$;
we won't use it here so as not to confuse it with the notation for sets.)
The sum $S$ can be rewritten as
$$
S \:=\: \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\,(x_{i+1}-x_i) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\fracpart{x_{i+1}-x_i}
    \:=\: x_n-x_1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\fracpart{x_{i+1}-x_i}.
$$
Since $1\leq x_1,\,x_n<n+1$ we have $-n<x_n-x_1<n$,
and since $0\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\fracpart{x_{i+1}-x_i}<n-1$,
it follows that $-2n+1<S<n$.
But $S$ is an integer, thus
$$
-2(n-1) \:\leq\: S \:\leq\: n-1~. \tag{2}
$$
Choosing $x_i=i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, we get $S=n-1$.
Choosing $x_i=n+1-i+\theta_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$,
for some real numbers $\theta_i$ satisfying the inequalities
$1>\theta_1>\theta_2>\cdots>\theta_n\geq0$
(for example,
the numbers $\theta_i=1-i/n$, $1\leq i\leq n$, fit the bill),
we have $\floor{x_{i+1}-x_i}=-2$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$,
so in this case we get $S=-2(n-1)$.

The answer is: the maximum value of $S$ is $n-1$,
while the minimum value of $S$ is $-2(n-1)$.

**Remarks.** $~$The suggestion of Macavity
that one needs seek the minimum and the maximum only over
integers $x_i$ is wrong:
the maximum $n-1$ can be attained by choosing $x_i=i$, $1\leq i\leq n$,
but the minimum $-2(n-1)$ is unattainable.
Indeed, if every $x_i$ is an integer,
then $\floor{x_{i+1}-x_i}=x_{i+1}-x_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$,
thus $S=x_n-x_1\geq -(n-1)>-2(n-1)$.
$\qquad$If you have carefully read the solution, you have surely noticed that the only
property of the numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, $\ldots$, $x_n$ we have used
to derive the bounds $(2)$ for $S$ was $$|x_n-x_1|<n \tag{3}~.$$
Thus the maximum and the minimum of $S$ remain the same if the $x_i$'s
are constrained by the weaker condition $(3)$ instead of the condition $(1)$.